# Unable to read sitemap: Google Search Console

Tags: http-error, google-crawlers, google-search-console, noindex, sitemap.xml

Sitemap could not be read
General HTTP error
1 instance
We encountered an error while trying to access your Sitemap. Please ensure your Sitemap follows our guidelines and can be accessed at the location you provided and then resubmit.
Examples
HTTP Error:500[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDg03.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the posts:

1. https://www.searchenginejournal.com/gsc-reports-sever-500-errors/375791/#close
2. https://support.google.com/webmasters/thread/66363365?hl=en

There can be errors in the code of the page or the structure. Google has set certain parameters based on which it decides to validate the submitted URLs and sitemaps.

It will be better if you can share the link of the problematic page so that one can try to catch what might be the issue.

For example:

> https://paragpallavsingh.com/sitemap.xml, this is an autogenerated sitemap by WordPress. and submitted in Google search console without any issue.